# Issue with Shopware Installation Using XAMPP: "Shopware Could Not Be Downloaded"

Tags: php, apache, shopware

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install Shopware using XAMPP. I followed a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8ufOH8kHmA) and successfully downloaded the shopware-installer.phar.php file into my xampp/htdocs/shopware folder.

After starting the Apache server, I navigated to http://localhost/shopware/shopware-installer.phar.php/install and configured the PHP binary field value to C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe on the page http://localhost/shopware/shopware-installer.phar.php/configure.

However, when I click the download button, I receive the following error message: "Shopware could not be downloaded. You can access the log file here."

The content of the log file is as follows:

```
Usage: C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                                         [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                                         [-w] [-k start|restart|stop|shutdown] [-n service_name]
                                         [-k install|config|uninstall] [-n service_name]
                                         [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -n name            : set service name and use its ServerConfigFile and ServerRoot
  -k start           : tell Apache to start
  -k restart         : tell running Apache to do a graceful restart
  -k stop|shutdown   : tell running Apache to shutdown
  -k install         : install an Apache service
  -k config          : change startup Options of an Apache service
  -k uninstall       : uninstall an Apache service
  -w                 : hold open the console window on error
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
  -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES: show all included configuration files
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
  -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing same problem, on WINDOWS OS, apparently, PHP binary field value C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe is wrong, it should be C:\xampp\php\php.exe which solves the problem...